# Pandas Rolling mean based on groupby multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I have a Long format dataframe with repeated values in two columns and data in another column. I want to find SMAs for each group. My problem is : `rolling()` simply ignores the fact that the data is grouped by two columns.

Here is some dummy data and code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dtix=pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019', periods=4) )
df=pd.DataFrame({'ix1':np.repeat([0,1],4), 'ix2':pd.concat([dtix,dtix]), 'data':np.arange(0,8) })
df
```

```
ix1 ix2 data
0   0   2019-01-01  0
1   0   2019-01-02  1
2   0   2019-01-03  2
3   0   2019-01-04  3
0   1   2019-01-01  4
1   1   2019-01-02  5
2   1   2019-01-03  6
3   1   2019-01-04  7
```

Now when I perform a grouped rolling mean on this data, I am getting an output like this:

```python
df.groupby(['ix1','ix2']).agg({'data':'mean'}).rolling(2).mean()
```

```
        data
ix1 ix2 
0   2019-01-01  NaN
    2019-01-02  0.5
    2019-01-03  1.5
    2019-01-04  2.5
1   2019-01-01  3.5
    2019-01-02  4.5
    2019-01-03  5.5
    2019-01-04  6.5
```

**Desired Output:**
Whereas, what I would actually like to have is this:

```
sma
ix1 ix2 
0   2019-01-01  NaN
    2019-01-02  0.5
    2019-01-03  1.5
    2019-01-04  2.5
1   2019-01-01  NaN
    2019-01-02  4.5
    2019-01-03  5.5
    2019-01-04  6.5
```

Will appreciate your help with this.

Comment: is that your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351322/pandas-moving-average-grouped-by-multiple-columns

Comment: You're not performing a rolling mean over the groups, as you've already applied an aggregation function over them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another `groupby` by firast level (`ix1`) with `rolling`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['ix1','ix2'])
         .agg({'data':'mean'})
         .groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)
         .rolling(2)
         .mean())
print (df1)
                data
ix1 ix2             
0   2019-01-01   NaN
    2019-01-02   0.5
    2019-01-03   1.5
    2019-01-04   2.5
1   2019-01-01   NaN
    2019-01-02   4.5
    2019-01-03   5.5
    2019-01-04   6.5
```

In your solution affter aggregation is returned one column `DataFrame`, so chained `rolling` working with all rows, not per groups like need:

```
print(df.groupby(['ix1','ix2']).agg({'data':'mean'}))
                data
ix1 ix2             
0   2019-01-01     0
    2019-01-02     1
    2019-01-03     2
    2019-01-04     3
1   2019-01-01     4
    2019-01-02     5
    2019-01-03     6
    2019-01-04     7
```

Comment: MAny thanks @jezreal and  @yatu. So my only groupby converted two columns to indices and the remaining  single column dataframe could not yield my desired result unless I grouped again by ix1 index? This means I could have done it simply by `df.set_index(("ix2"), inplace=False).groupby("ix1")["data"].rolling(2).mean()` , am I right? (Ok I have checked it works, but somehow I expect a simple groupby over multiple columns should have done the trick. Guess I need to think about how groupby works  )  .Thanks again.

Comment: @R.S. - yes, you are right - also is possible it simplify by `df.set_index("ix2").groupby("ix1")["data"].rolling(2).mean()`